# How to display Form using function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am super new to the React JS and bootstrap. trying to load the login form using React JS class and embedded function in that.

however, on the click event, the function is not rendering the Form but displaying the console logs.

below is the code

**home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactBootstrap, {
  Navbar,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  Button,
  Form,
  FormControl,
  NavDropdown
} from "react-bootstrap";


import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

export default class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props)
{
  super(props);
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  
  this.state = {
   toggleLogin: false
   
  }
}

handleClick = () => {
    console.log('Click happened');
    console.log(this.state.toggleLogin);
    return <div>
      <form>
                <h3>Sign In</h3>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" className="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" />
                        <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor="customCheck1">Remember me</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
                <p className="forgot-password text-right">
                    Forgot <a href="#">password?</a>
                </p>
            </form>

    </div>
    
      }

    render() {
   
      return (

    
   <div>
         <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
           <Navbar.Brand href="/">abc</Navbar.Brand>
           <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
           <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
             <Nav className="mr-auto links">
               <Link to={this.state.toggleLogin} onClick={this.handleClick}>Log In</Link>
              </Nav>
           </Navbar.Collapse>
         </Navbar>
  
         </div>
);
}
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Home from './home';
import ReactBootstrap, {
  Navbar,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  Button,
  Form,
  FormControl,
  NavDropdown
} from "react-bootstrap";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
      <Switch>

        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
       </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

why the form is not getting displayed?

Comment: Seems typo is here `return <div><form>`. You may need `(` like `return (<div><form>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you want to render this Form? you don't add the Form in the render so you will not see it, but the function is called correct. So All you need is something like that:

```
this.state = {
   toggleLogin: false;
}

const renderForm = () => (
    <form>Your form here</form>
)

const handleClick = () => {
    console.log('Click happened');
    this.setState(this.state.toggleLogin: !toggleLogin) // this way if you want to toggle
}
    
render() {
    return (
        <div>{this.state.toggleLogin && renderForm()}</div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is exactly what you're looking for

https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

`handleClick` is just a callback for an event, so it's not gonna effect what'll be rendered.

I guess you want some thing like

```js
render() {
    return (
        ...
        {toggleLogin && <FormLogin />}
        ...
    )
}
```